# Using jQuery date picker to dynamically populate dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, multidimensional-array, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form that a user fills out. First the user selects a store. Then the user selects a date from a calendar, using the jQuery Datepicker plugin. Based on which store the user selects and which DAY of the week the user selects from the calendar (Monday, Tuesday, etc). then that will determine which times will appear in the third dropdown. Here is my html:

```
<form action="/CustomerService-FFEventBookAppointment">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-row"><label for="store">Preferred Store *</label>

<div class="chzn-row valid">
  <select class="chzn-global-select input-select optional required" id="store" name="store">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Martin Place">Martin Place</option>
    <option value="Chatswood Chase">Chatswood Chase</option>
    <option value="Emporium">Emporium</option>
    <option value="Indooroopilly">Indooroopilly</option>
    <option value="Collins Street">Collins Street</option>
    <option value="DJ Market Street">DJ Market Street</option>
    <option value="DJ Bourke Street Mens">DJ Bourke Street Mens</option>
    <option value="DJ Bourke Street Womens">DJ Bourke Street Womens</option>
    <option value="DJ Queen Street">DJ Queen Street</option>
    <option value="DJ Rundle Mall">DJ Rundle Mall</option> 
  </select>
</div>

</div>

<div class="form-row"><label for="date">Date *</label>
```

And below is my JavaScript. You can view the full thing on my JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katherinekonn/qquprwhg/

```
<div class="chzn-row valid">
      <input type="text" lass="chzn-global-select input-select optional required" id="datepicker" name="date">
</div>

</div>

<div class="form-row"><label for="time">Time * </label>

<div class="chzn-row valid">
    <select class="chzn-global-select input-select optional required" id="time" name="time">
        <option value=""></option> 
    </select>
</div>

</div>

    var dayByStore = {
       "Martin Place": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
       "Chatswood Chase": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
    };

    var timeByDayByStore = {
        "Martin Place":{
          "Friday":[
            "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
            "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
          ],
          "Saturday":[
            "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
            "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Sunday":[
            "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
            "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
            "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
            "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Monday":[
            "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
            "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
          ],
          "Tuesday":[
            "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM"
          ],
          "Wednesday":[
            "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
            "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
          ],
          "Thursday":[
            "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
            "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM"
          ],
          },
          "Chatswood Chase":{
          "Friday":[
            "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Saturday":[
            "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Sunday":[
            "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Monday":[
            "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Tuesday":[
            "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Wednesday":[
            "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
            "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
            "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
          ],
          "Thursday":[
            "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
          ],
        },
    };


  $( function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy' });
  } );

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#datepicker', function(){
           var store = $('#store option:selected').val();
            var timeOptions = "";
                for (timeId in timeByDayByStore[store][date]) {
                    timeOptions += "<option value='" + timeByDayByStore[store][date][timeId]  + "'>" + timeByDayByStore[store][date][timeId] + "</option>";
                }
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeOptions;
    })
  })
```

Can anyone help me with the function? I'm still very new, but I need to somehow have the time dropdown become populated by times based on what store and what day of the week from the calendar the user selects, and I can't quite figure out the logic. Help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Take care, you're lacking some `</div>`. Anyway, I'm working on your issue. Use [ Tidy ] in your fiddle, it helps founding them!

Comment: See my updated answer, I added useful comments in all my JS code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet,
where I only made modifications at the end of the JS.
I removed the "personal" parts to make the snippet shorter,
and added some comments in my code to make it clearer!

```js
var dayByStore = {
  "Martin Place": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "Chatswood Chase": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "Emporium": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "Indooroopilly": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "Collins Street": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "DJ Market Street": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "DJ Bourke Street Mens": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "DJ Bourke Street Womens": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "DJ Queen Street": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
  "DJ Rundle Mall": ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"],
};

var timeByDayByStore = {
  "Martin Place": {
    "Friday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "Chatswood Chase": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "Emporium": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wesnesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "Indooroopilly": {
    "Friday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "Collins Street": {
    "Friday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "DJ Market Street": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "DJ Bourke Street Mens": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "DJ Bourke Street Womens": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "DJ Queen Street": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
  "DJ Rundle Mall": {
    "Friday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
    "Saturday": [
      "9:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Sunday": [
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM"
    ],
    "Monday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Wednesday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM"
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      "10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
      "11:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
      "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM",
      "1:00 PM - 2:00 PM",
      "2:00 PM - 3:00 PM",
      "3:00 PM - 4:00 PM",
      "4:00 PM - 5:00 PM",
      "5:00 PM - 6:00 PM",
      "6:00 PM - 7:00 PM",
      "7:00 PM - 8:00 PM",
      "8:00 PM - 9:00 PM"
    ],
  },
};

var user_store = '';
var user_day = '';

// Function where the options are updated
function update_time() {
  
  // Empty the options list
  $('#time').empty();

  // Exits function if there's no store, or no day.
  if (!user_store || !user_day) return;
  
  // Gets the open hours of the user selected store and day
  var open_hours = timeByDayByStore[user_store][user_day];

  // Fills the options list
  $.each(open_hours, function(key, value) {
    $('#time')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", key)
        .text(value));
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy',
    // Added action on selection of a date
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      // Here, we split the value of the datepicker to get the day, like "Monday"
      user_day = dateText.split(',')[0];
      // Then, we call the update function!
      update_time();
    }
  });
});

// Call the function when changing the store, too!
$('#store').on('change', function(){
  user_store = $('#store').val();
  update_time();
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ffEventContainer">
    <div id="ffEvent">
      <div id="ffHeader">
        <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="line lineRight">&nbsp;</div>

        <h1>Time &amp; Venue</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="ffLanding">
        <form action="/CustomerService-FFEventBookAppointment">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-row"><label for="store">Preferred Store *</label>

              <div class="chzn-row valid">
                <select class="chzn-global-select input-select optional required" id="store" name="store">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="Martin Place">Martin Place</option>
                  <option value="Chatswood Chase">Chatswood Chase</option>
                  <option value="Emporium">Emporium</option>
                  <option value="Indooroopilly">Indooroopilly</option>
                  <option value="Collins Street">Collins Street</option>
                  <option value="DJ Market Street">DJ Market Street</option>
                  <option value="DJ Bourke Street Mens">DJ Bourke Street Mens</option>
                  <option value="DJ Bourke Street Womens">DJ Bourke Street Womens</option>
                  <option value="DJ Queen Street">DJ Queen Street</option>
                  <option value="DJ Rundle Mall">DJ Rundle Mall</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row"><label for="date">Date *</label>
              <div class="chzn-row valid">
                <input type="text" lass="chzn-global-select input-select optional required" id="datepicker" name="date">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row"><label for="time">Time * </label>
              <div class="chzn-row valid">
                <select class="chzn-global-select input-select optional required" id="time" name="time">
                  <option value=""></option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much :) those comments are super helpful! works perfectly

Comment: I modified it just a little  right now, and it's better commented. Take care, in your arrays I found one "Wesnesday". You should review it!

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look on my JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1bx2ccb0/1/

```
const time = document.getElementById("time");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#datepicker', function() {
    var store = $('#store option:selected').val();
    const date = document.getElementById("datepicker").value.split(',')[0];
    time.innerHTML = "";
    timeByDayByStore[store][date].forEach(timeByDay => {
      const option = new Option(timeByDay, timeByDay)
      time.add(option);
    });
  })
})
```